# How can I get the results of a stored procedure using SSIS?

Tags: ssis, oledb

I have stored procedure that will run a complex select statement and will show the results.
I need to use this stored procedure within a data flow. I tried to use the EXECUTE within OLEDB source but I got an error. I am guessing it's because of a large dataset? because I tried it with another SP that will give only 1 row and it worked!
so how can I get the results of the SP and use it in my data flow?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post what error you get?

Comment: Please provide the error message and the version of SSIS as well as the version of SQL Server you are trying to use the stored procedure against. My bet is that the error message pertains "to unable to determine metadata" and the resolution is going to be specific to SQL Server - either stuff in a fake result set shape (2005-2008R2)  or an explicit shape, WITH RESULTS SET, (2012-current)